# wordpress user registration optional fileds with php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, registration, createuser

The WordPress registration default function just have 3 options:

```
 <?php wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); ?>
```

If I want to add some other fileds, like `age` or `somtehing else!`
with written PHP form, how can I do this?

`wp_users` have some columns, like 
`user_login & user_email $ user_status`. Can I add new column like `age`?
And, if I can, how can I register it with php page?

Like function:

```
wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ,$age);
```

If it's impossible, 
how can I create a new table, like `wp_specialusers`
and access to it using PHP, like:

```
wpdb::query('insert something to wp_specialusers..?') or
mysql_query('insert ...')
```

I want like this

```
<?php /* Template Name: wallet */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<form action=" --->WHERE!?<--- " method="post">
AGE : <input type="text" name="age">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

tnx a lot

Comment: No, you don’t do this by adding new columns to the user table, nor by creating your own table. Use the proper meta data functionality as it already exists! https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Comment: tanx but its just can change user meta if i want set user name or lastname Simultaneous sign up i cant use it

Comment: Maybe you should rather look into ACF then. That provides relatively easy ways to configure additional meta fields, _and_ to automatically attach according form fields in different places (such as the user profile.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to use the `wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email )` function like you originally have and then you need to run the [wp_update_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/) function afterwards to insert additional data. The additional data columns should already exist. If you want to add custom additional user data then you should use a plugin such as AdvancedCustomFields

```
<?php
$user_id = // ID of the user you just created;

$website = 'http://example.com'; // additional data

$user_data = wp_update_user( 
   array( 
     'ID' => $user_id,
     'user_url' => $website
   )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $user_data ) ) {
    // There was an error; possibly this user doesn't exist.
    echo 'Error.';
} else {
    // Success!
    echo 'User profile updated.';
}
?>
```

> Update: OP wants to insert additional data at the same time of creation.

Then use [wp_insert_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)

```
// Extra info to add
$website = "http://example.com";
$nickname = "Superman";
$description = "My description."

$userdata = array(
    'user_login' =>  'login_name',
    'user_url'   =>  $website,
    'nickname'   =>  $nickname,
    'description'=>  $description,
    'user_pass'  =>  NULL // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

// On success.
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}
```

Comment: i want user do it At the same time with sign up i think it has 2 levels

Comment: @DanialQsk you want users to add `php` code? you should write your own logic, which users will use.ex. - if you added code for processing/adding field {`Like football` : yes/no }, then you should to add   input with php/html related to `Like Football`, and after add php code to process it ( clear and check input ), and after add information into `usermeta` table. what's not clear from written above?

Comment: nooo i just want my simple sign up form white some more options like age telephon and other else

Comment: so, use `add_user_meta()` function. it'll add any fields you want into `usermeta` table of your database. and will relate to the user

Comment: i want it at the same time with <?php wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); 
and i havent user id for add user meta to this user 

i want backend for https://image.ibb.co/f9rYMx/Untitled.jpg

Comment: @DanialQsk `wp_create_user()` returns the `ID` of the last person if it is successful in creating the user. I've updated my answer with a different function. You should really watch some basic tutorials on how WP works, or better yet, just read the documentation.